# False eyelashes: eye candy for onlookers or just eye candy for bacteria?

Tags: eyelash, trachoma

Catch someone's eye -- don't catch bacteria for your eye.

A few of my friends don on false eyelashes -- some do it for special occasions, others almost wear them everyday. I have never asked them, because I didn't want to appear to disapprove of their decision to do so (if they are cool with it, then hey... fine), but ***aren't there a lot of health risks involved with wearing false eyelashes?***

Personally, just being very sensitive to **adhesives,** I get all **itchy** just thinking about having false eyelashes glued to my eyelid. And I know if I had it done, that I would constantly be **rubbing my eyes,** which would **introduce more bacteria to them**, leading to things like **trachoma, stys,** etc. ***But is this not a common side-effect of wearing false eyelashes?***

Also, I would be afraid that all the false eyelashes would put pressure on my natural eyelashes when I blink, and would result in thinning or loss of my natural eyelashes. ***Does thinning or loss of natural eyelashes result because of false eyelashes?***